# Running Python With Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I have notepad++ version v6.9.1 and python 3.5 (32 bit).  Running Windows 10.  I need to be able to run my python code, but when I try to download the PyNPP plugin (this is what I use at school) it gives me and error message saying the it isn't compatible with the version of NPP.

Comment: You could add a Run command in Notepad++ for Python. Run > Modify Shortcut/Delete Command

Comment: I find it easier to keep a terminal window open (like cmd) and just running things from that.

Comment: What benefit is NPP over IDLE?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plugin to run Python code from NotePad++.

Just press F5 and then depending on the location of Python you will type:

```
C:\Python32\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Of course, you will have to replace `C:\Python32\python.exe` with the location of your Python installation.

You can also save this as a keyboard shortcut, just click save, and input the keyboard shortcut you would like to use.

Comment: C:\Users\Nanders\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" Like this @Viliami

Comment: Because whenever I use that code and I click run nothing happens

Comment: @NoahAnderson if you're clicking "Run" and nothing is happening, it is most likely because the command you entered is incorrect. Are you sure that is the correct file path for python? Copy and paste it into explorer and see if it shows up.

Comment: I checked where it is and my code was wrong, but when I put this in:

Comment: C:\Users\Nanders\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python

Comment: It opens and then closes

Comment: That might have happened because of a syntax error in your code, therefore it stops running and then closes quickly. Run it through CMD and check that there it runs correctly

Comment: Sometimes running Python directly from notepad++ gives access error, so I prefer to use `[PATH_to_the_Python]\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat  "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and then run from IDLE